# Android. ImageView wrap in FrameLayout

Tags: android, imageview

I want imageView wrap in FrameLayout. And ImageView show fullscreen.

1 variant:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout       
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffff00" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_draw"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#00ff00">
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/vertical_test"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: var1]
<sub>(source: [cs412821.vk.me](http://cs412821.vk.me/v412821867/8ea9/OvNBg1prQCc.jpg))</sub>

2 variant:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout       
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffff00" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_draw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#00ff00">
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/vertical_test"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: var2]
<sub>(source: [cs412821.vk.me](http://cs412821.vk.me/v412821867/8eb0/_yyXwtXwH8Y.jpg))</sub>

AdjustViewBounds not working.

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image: var1]
<sub>(source: [cs412821.vk.me](http://cs412821.vk.me/v412821867/8eb7/f_exSEp-z9I.jpg))</sub>

How do I handle this? Thank you very much. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Change your imageview attributes from :

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/vertical_test"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

To:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/vertical_test"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

It also depends on how tall your image is.. If you know the width and height, you can adjust it accordingly.

Also, you can use gravity attribute if you want the want the image to be in the center position.

Comment: Do a fill_parent android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" and same with the frame layout attributes. I'll change the answer.

Comment: Is then ![var2](http://cs412821.vk.me/v412821867/8eb0/_yyXwtXwH8Y.jpg). See 2 variant.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? I am still not clear with the question now.

Comment: I want imageView wrap in FrameLayout. And ImageView show fullscreen. Then, in frameLayout add another view.

Comment: One request.. can you just add a image that shows your final result you want to achieve. It shouldn't take long in paint.

Comment: No. Then, in frameLayout add another view.